# Adding Radius Attribute to each Polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

[image: Picture of the Map right now]

Is it possible to add the Radius for each Clipped Polygon to its Attribute Table?
So far I only have the Area (Fläche) in square metres but I also need the radius for each Hub in its own area/polygon

Comment: 'Radius' as in the shortest line from each hub to the nearest polygon boundary?

Comment: Yes, in thise case the hubs are the center and the boundary lines are my perimeter

Comment: something like distance( centroid(  $geometry ),  ( closest_point( centroid(  $geometry ) , $geometry)) ) should do it, but this only returns 0 for all polygons - you need to find the closest point on the polygon not just the vertexes which is what I think closest_point does

Comment: @iant your idea was correct, but it only returns `0` because it finds the closest point from a feature (which will be often `0` since the centroid generally lies on the feature itself). Using the `boundary` function, instead, it becomes possible evaluating the shortest distance (as explained in my answer).

Comment: @geologic, was my solution helpful for you?

Answer (score 7):

You may use the following code from the **Field Calculator**:

```
length(
 shortest_line(
  centroid($geometry),
  boundary($geometry)
 )
)
```

It will compute the length of the shortest line which connects the centroid of each polygon feature to the boundary of the feature itself.

The best would be creating a new field for which the above code would be applied.